# unexpected output is occurred

Tags: java, arraylist

the expected output of the code should be:  "Everything (else) is ok"

but when i run my the sky class: the actual output is the following:

Bad StratusCloud::rain(unexpected)
Bad CumulusCloud::rain(unexpected)
Bad mean height: expected 1800, saw -1800.0(unexpected)
**Everything (else) is ok**(expected)

the following is my code:

```
package weather;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Sky {
    private ArrayList<Cloud> clouds;
public Sky(){
    clouds = new ArrayList<Cloud>(100);
}

public boolean add(Cloud c){

    clouds.add(c);
    return true;
}


public float getMeanHeight()
{
float mean = 0;
float sum = 0;
for (Cloud c:clouds){
    sum  = sum +c.getHeight(); 
    mean = sum/(clouds.size());
}
return mean;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
StratusCloud strat = new StratusCloud(100, 1000);
if (!strat.rain().startsWith("It is raining"))
System.out.println("Bad StratusCloud::rain");
CumulusCloud cumu = new CumulusCloud(200, 2000);
if (!cumu.rain().startsWith("It is raining"))
System.out.println("Bad CumulusCloud::rain");
CirrusCloud cirr = new CirrusCloud(300, 3000);
if (!cirr.rain().startsWith("I cannot make"))
System.out.println("Bad CirrusCloud::rain");
Sky sky = new Sky();
sky.add(strat);
sky.add(cumu);
sky.add(cirr);
float mean = sky.getMeanHeight();
if (mean < 1799 || mean > 1801)
System.out.println("Bad mean height: expected 1800, saw " + mean);
System.out.println("Everything (else) is ok");
}
}
```

Superclass Cloud:

```
   package weather;

public class Cloud 
{
    private float top;
    private float bottom;


    public Cloud(float top, float bottom)
    {
        this.top = top;
        this.bottom = bottom;
    }

    public float getHeight()
    {
        float height = top - bottom;
        return height;
    }

    public String rain()
    {
        String raining = "It is rainning";
        return raining;
    }
}
```

the following are sub classes of Cloud:(name of the 2 classes:CumulusCloud,StratusCloud)

```
package weather;

public class "name" extends Cloud 
{
public "name"(float top,float bottom)
{
    super(top,bottom);
}
}
```

the subclass of Cloud that is override:

```
package weather;

public class CirrusCloud extends Cloud{
    public CirrusCloud(float top, float bottom)
    {
        super(top,bottom);
    }
public String rain(){
    super.rain();
    String raining ="I cannot make rain";
    return raining;
}
}
```

Comment: This does not compile.  You cannot put a class name in quotes: `class "name"` is wrong.  Please show us the actual code that produces your output.

Comment: compiler error Syntax error on token ""name", Identifier expected.

Comment: I believe OP is indicating that there are two identical classes that differ only by "name" (*`CumulusCloud`* and *`StratusCloud`*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the spelling. In your Cloud class it is

> rainning

But in Sky class

> raining